# Issue with ember-bootstrap: page background rendered half gray, should normally be totally white

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-bootstrap

I have a small issue with Bootstrap. Sometime, my page background is half white/ half gray, but it should be all white.

[image]

As you can see, there is some gray background in my application, somebody know how to get rid of it. I'm knew to CSS, so if you need any information about my problem, ask me! Thank you!

**EDIT**
This is the code for my body:

```
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```

I am using a default page-wrapper for the content of every element. He is not defined anywhere.

SOLVED:
Thanks to @KieranMcClung, it was solved. You can see in the comment if you want, but basically, I put in my page-wrapper something like:

```
<div id="page-wrapper" style="height: auto; min-height: 100vh">
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide some code, either by attaching to the question (ideally) or adding a link to codepen/jsfiddle? It's nigh on impossible to figure out the issue without the code. My assumption is that the content element (white) falls short of the screen height so the body colour shows beneath it.

Comment: I have to resize my browser to standardize the page in white, maybe that can help?

Comment: @KieranMcClung I have to manually set the page-wrapper min-height to 1000px to correct it, but since I am trying to avoid using pixel, maybe there is an other solution?

Comment: Setting `min-height: 100vh` will ensure the `.page-wrapper` class is always 100% height of the window.

Comment: OK that fixed it, thanks a lot

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help. I've added it as an answer with a bit more information.

Comment: Why not just change the background color to #FFF on your body tag instead of trying to stretch a sub element?

Comment: I have a side-menu on the left, and it render better with the bottom of this side menu in gray. For commercial reason too, the colors of the society are orange and gray ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example will ensure the `.page-wrapper` class is always at 100% screen height.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <!-- Page content -->
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.page-wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100vh; /* Important bit */
}
```

It's worth noting that `vh` can have varied results on certain mobile browsers because the top browser bar disappears when scrolling, meaning the screen height (vh value), changes. You'll have to bear this in mind when testing on those devices.